# Why HTML5 Password input type doesn't work if an HTML5 text input is used in subsequent line?

Tags: html

If I use the below code, it would not print the HTML5 invalidate error:

```
Enter your 4 digit Pin
<label class="item item-input">
<span class="input-label">Password</span>
<input type="password" maxlength=4 pattern="[a-z]">
</label>
<input type="text">
<input type="button">
```

However If I remove the 2nd text input type, it would show me an invalid input error on pressing enter or clicking the button.

The below code works fine:

```
Enter your 4 digit Pin
<label class="item item-input">
<span class="input-label">Password</span>
<input type="password" maxlength=4 pattern="[a-z]">
</label>    
<input type="button">
```

[image]

Comment: As a sidenote, the pattern should be `"^[a-z]{4}$"` as currently it is okay if there is even one letter (e.g. `a` is valid, `5a!` is valid and `7h아&` is valid)

Comment: Thanks @Artyer, but could you please answer why adding a new text tag just below this makes the password field not working anymore?

Comment: That's actually what fixed it for me on chrome/firefox. What browser is this on?

Comment: I am using Chrome's latest version. The thing is, as soon as I add a new input type=text element, the password field no longer shows the invalid message for wrong patterns. Without any subsequent text fields, the field shows the error as seen in above screenshot